# List all errors in an IntelliJ module

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

When there's an error in a file, IntelliJ underlines the relevant code in red and marks the position of the error in red on the right-hand side of the editor, e.g.

[image: example error]

Is there some way that I can get a list of all errors in a module? I know IntelliJ has a "Problems" view, but I can't seem to display it, and I'm pretty sure low-level errors like this aren't shown in it anyway (IIRC it only shows project-wide problems such as missing dependencies).

In my case the module is a Grails app, so it contains both server-side (Groovy) code and front-end code (JS, HTML, CSS, etc.). If I run "Build Project" (or "Build Module") any errors in the JS code aren't listed in the output, presumably because JS code doesn't have to be built (compiled).

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA version 2018.3.3 (Ultimate Edition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Select the module you wish to inspect in the Project pane on the left of the IDE
- On the main menu, choose Analyze | Inspect Code
- In the Inspection scope area, specify which files should be inspected
- Click OK to run code analysis

Examine the results

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Build | Build Project shows all errors in the project.

Comment: In my case the module is a Grails app, so it contains both server-side (Groovy) code and front-end code (JS, HTML, CSS, etc.). Any errors in the JS code don't show up in the output of "Build Project" (or "Build Module"), presumably because JS code doesn't have to be built (compiled).